# Notification.onclick property not working in electronjs

Tags: electron

I am going through the documentation on electronjs and i've just gotten to the part about notifications and adding clicking events. I added the notification.onclick property but when i click on the notification after running the app, nothing gets shown on the console. This is the code in the renderer.js file.

```
    let myNotification = new Notification('Title', {
        body: 'Notification from the Renderer Process'
    })

    myNotification.onclick = () => {
        console.log("Notification clicked")
    }
```

Can anyone tell me where i am going wrong?

Comment: It worked fine with me, can you provide more details about your environment? OS, electron version...

Comment: I finally figured it out. I had focus assist on and it was set to alarms only and hence it was blocking the banner notifications. When i click the banner notification, the message is logged on the console. Now the issue is that when i try to interact with the notification from the action center. Any suggestions on how i can solve that? Environment Windows 10 Home, electron version 12.0.6